# Как выполнить Интернет-запрос в Qt?

Tags: qt, c++, сеть

При выполнении в браузере команды:

> http://apifree.forvo.com/key/bc78c6774d956410631a5c9ad27dd569/format/xml/action/word-pronunciations/word/cat/language/en

в ответ браузер выдает xml-файл

1) и тут у меня сразу первый вопрос: как правильно называется эта команда (скрипт, интернет-команда)?

2) Как в Qt выполнить этот запрос и получить файл xml?

Файл напрямую из интернет я загружал так:

```
void downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager m_NetworkMngr;
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_NetworkMngr.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),&loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    QUrl aUrl(url);
    QFileInfo fileInfo=aUrl.path();

    QFile file(aPathInClient + "/" + fileInfo.fileName());
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(reply->readAll());

    delete reply;

}

void myprocedure()
{
    QString path;
    QString localPath;

    path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
    path += "/Downloads";

    localPath = path;
    downloadFile ("http://site.com/text.txt", localPath);

}
```

А как быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> А как быть в этом случае?

Точно так же. Ему глубоко фиолетово какой именно отдаётся контент.